# When do you put the comma before "like" in a list

Tags: grammar, commas

Is there any difference between putting a comma or omitting it when you say "like" in a list?

For example, in the phrase "While I was visiting the zoo, I saw many different animals, like zebras, giraffes, and more.

Is there a difference if you remove the comma before like, or is it a matter of choice?

Comment: ***like*** (and equivalents like ***such as, for example,...***) isn't "in" the list - it ***precedes*** the list. Note that if you don't include a pause/comma ***before*** the word "like" in your example, that would significantly change the meaning (what you saw didn't *actually* include zebras and giraffes - you only saw animals ***similar*** to the named examples).

Comment: If you remove the comma, it becomes a verb. It means that you saw many different animals **engaged in being fond of** zebras  … (*I saw many different animals **eat** zebras. I saw many different animals **hurt** zebras. I saw many different **like** [verb] zebras.*

Comment: The comma indicates that it's a "parenthetical".

Answer (score 1):

From what I've learned in my time at school/From my personal experience, you are correct to put a comma before "like" in the sentence you used as an example.
Yes, in your example, there is a difference if you were to remove that comma.

Your example (**WITH comma**): "While I was visiting the zoo, I saw many different animals, like zebras, giraffes, and more."

Your example (**WITHOUT comma**): "While I was visiting the zoo, I saw many different animals like zebras, giraffes, and more."

Without the comma before "like," it would mean that *the zebras, giraffes, and more* **draw attention** from the *many different animals*, or it would mean that the *many different animals* are **pleased with** *the zebras, giraffes, and more*.

I'm unable to come up with an example that contradicts this because I struggle with making stuff up, and I'm on a tight schedule. If someone else can come up with an opposing example, that would be great.

I wish you good fortune and good health.